# The node.js express:can not get the data posted by jquery ajax

Tags: node.js, post, express

In client side, I use jquery to post data:

```
        var data = {
            'city': 'england'
        }
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'post',
            'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
            'data': data,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function () {
                console.log('success');
            }
        })
```

In my server.js, I try to catch the post data:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
app.listen(8000);
```

the post could success, it return 200 status, but I can't log the post data, it return nothing, and the terminal log `undefined`.

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending the data right.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: '/endpoint'
});
```

With jQuery, use

> contentType:'application/json'

to send JSON data.

Comment: No,it still doesn't work,the contentType have change to json.But the data posted still can not be show

Comment: What version of express are you using? I am on 2.5.8